# Fails to send email with smtpClient in port 465

Tags: c#, port, smtpclient

I'm using SmtpClient to send email. But when I use it with Port 465 it fails. It works with the following ports: 587 & 25.
I read that ports 25 and 587 are for TLS, while port 465 for SSL.

Im using enableSSL as true, and I'm sending from gmail to gmail account.

Comment: gmail has very specific ports, servers, and additional account configuration could be needed. Check for similar questions https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+gmail